# how to pass special character to another page using query string in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

```
 onclick="javascript:openWin('printselectedn.jsp?
CTextSearch=<%=finalsearch1%>&CTextNumbr=<%=Mytext1%>&
CYear=<%=Ciryear1%>&
CSectionNo=<%=secNo1%>
&CDatefrom=<%=Datefrom%>&
CDateto=<%=DateTo%>','circular')">
```

This is My code of Query String I am sending   CTextSearch to another jsp Page using Query String .when i Input Business Losses then it pass correctly to another page But when i take Input "Business Losses" then also It pass to Another page as  Business Losses same But i want "Business Losses"  it does not take special character     please tell me how pass special charter in Using Query String Jsp pages.

Comment: Did you try URLEncoder and URLDecoder?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: please Update with Mycode i hatried But not able to do

Comment: I'd say ```CTextSearch=<%=URLEncoder.encode(finalsearch1,'UTF-8')%>```.
And then you'll need to do ```URLDecoder.decode``` on the other page

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the scriptlets, and learn [the JSP EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and [the JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info):

```
<c:url var="theUrl value="printselectedn.jsp">
    <c:param name="CTextSearch" value="${finalsearch1}"/>
    <c:param name="CTextNumbr" value="${Mytext1}"/>
    ... you getthe idea
</c:url>

onclick="javascript:openWin('<c:out value="${theUrl}"/>')"
```

Scriplets should not be used in JSPs for more than 10 years. Don't use scriptlets.